# Por que não podemos retornar uma chamada void em um método que espera retorno void?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, método, return

Eu estava fazendo uns testes em C# para saber como funciona a questão do retorno `void`.

Eu fiz os seguintes teste abaixo e percebi que os testes 1 e 3 funcionam perfeitamente, porém o 2 não.

Veja:

```
public class Program
{

    public void Test1()
    {
    }

    public void Test2()
    {

        return Test1();
    }

    public void Test3()
    {
        return;
    }

}
```

Erro gerado:

> since 'Program.Test2()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Minha pergunta é: Por que é gerado um erro na declaração de `Test2`, sendo que ele de fato retorna um `void`?

O teste foi feito no [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XGSv5y)

Comment: Creio que isto responde a parte técnica [Why can a void method in C++ return a void value, but in other languages it cannot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36445743/1518921), sobre a passagem que esperam certos "tipos".

Comment: Quem negativou poderia fazer uma contribuição com um comentário, falando sobre o que pode ser melhorado na pergunta?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Existe uma coisa chamada [*Type System*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) que é um conjunto de regras que determinam como os dados vão se comportar e o que pode fazer com eles. Baseia-se na [teoria de tipos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory).

Então todas as estruturas de dados da linguagem de alguma forma estão baseadas nessas regras estabelecidas pelo sistema de tipos da linguagem que está usando.

Portanto as regras para o [`void`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.void?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) são especiais. Faz sentido ser assim? Acho que faz. Faria sentido ele ser um tipo normal? Até faria. Cada decisão tem sua implicação.

Um `return` pode ser usado sem nada ou pode ser usado com uma expressão. Sem nada só pode ser usado se a assinatura do método indica que não deve retornar alguma coisa (com o `void`). Se o método é `void` não pode retornar alguma coisa, e a sintaxe usada está retornando alguma coisa.

Aí você vai dizer:

> não está retornando algo, o método chamado é `void` e `void` indica que não existe algo ali

ou dizer:

> está retornando `void` para algo que espera `void`

Sim, mas isso é circunstancial, pode mudar. Mas o pior é que dá a entender que algo está sendo retornado já que batendo o olho em `return algumacoisa` parece que tem algo aí, só uma investigação mais aprofundada indicará que até é adequado.

Além disso é uma questão de consistência, em vários lugares não pode usar assim, porque deixaria usar no `return`? Que ganho espera ter com isso?

Então definiu-se que qualquer método que seja `void` só pode ser chamado onde se espera um *statement* e não onde se espera uma expressão. Isso é mais legível e funciona bem sem nenhum ponto negativo:

```
Test1();
return;
```

Quer por em uma linha?

```
Test1(); return;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Void.cs).

Qualquer *feature* precisa se pagar. Tem que haver um justificativa para sua adoção, tem que dar um benefício real e não cobrar nada significativo.

Informalmente até falamos "o método retorna `void`", mas isso está conceitualmente errado.

Outras linguagens podem adotar postura diferente.

Tem [proposta para permitir isso](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/135), mas não foi muito bem aceita. [Outra](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11330).

[Resposta canônica](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/131036/389).

Comment: É interessante dizer que, na linguagem `Kotlin`, existe um tipo correspondente ao `void`, que é o `Unit`, e ele pode fazer exatamente o que o autor perguntou. :)

Comment: A questão da "uma linha" foi exatamente o que eu estava procurando. Interessante sua resposta +1

Answer (score 7):

Porque não faz sentido nenhum.

Se o método é `void`, **nada vai ser retornado**, então não faz nenhum sentido tentar retornar algo, mesmo que seja o retorno de uma função que também seja `void`.

Se você precisa chamar a função `Test1()` antes de terminar `Test2`, apenas chame a função.

```
public void Test1() { }

public void Test2() 
{
    Test1();
}
```

Comment: Mas, se o `Test2` retornasse o `int` e `Test1` também, daria certo. No caso `void` não seria "um tipo"?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Não, `void` é nada.

Comment: @LINQ eu acho que o void é algo quando se esta usando ponteiros, na verdade ele pode ser qualquer coisa, se os ponteiros do C# for como da linguagem C.

Comment: @gato Aí é uma questão beeeeeeeeeeeeeem diferente. Primeiro que o compilador nem deixa existir ponteiro sem estar dentro de um bloco `unsafe`, o que quer dizer que é um caso bem especial

Answer (score 2):

Conforme o link da documentação [*void (C# Reference) <sup>(en)</sup>*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/void), quando usa `void` ele especifica que o método não irá retornar nenhum valor

O `void` também é usado em um *contexto desprotegido* para declarar um ponteiro para um *tipo desconhecido*, note também que `void` é um apelido para [**`System.Void` <sup>(en)</sup>**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.void?view=netcore-2.0) e conforme o link afirma que quando usado ele irá especificar que o tipo do retorno não deve retornar valor, então o que entendo disto é que mesmo que `System.Void` seja:

- `Object` ⇢ `ValueType` ⇢ `Void`

Ainda sim o método aonde aplicou `return Teste2();` já esta *marcado* para não retornar nada e portanto no método não será aceito nenhuma expressão dentro de `return`, então quando você adiciona `Teste2()` dentro de `return` ele será uma expressão, independente do tipo de valor que `Test2()` retorne.

Você poderia até fazer algo como `public in Teste2()` (mesmo que **não** faça sentido, isto é só para explicar aonde ocorre a "avaliação") que iria obter o mesmo erro:

```
A return keyword must not be followed by any expression when method returns void
```

> **Nota:** a tradução de
>
> ```
> A return keyword must not be followed by any expression
> when method returns void
> ```
>
> seria algo como:
>
> ```
> Uma palavra-chave `return` não deve ser seguida por qualquer
> expressão quando o método retorna `void`
> ```

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que a instrução *return* finaliza a execução do método em que aparece e retorna o controle para o método de chamada. Ela também pode retornar um valor opcional. Se o método for um tipo *void*, a instrução *return* poderá ser omitida e na ocasião de usar em um método de retorno *void*, o uso do *return* irá fazer com que nada a baixo dele execute e assim retornando o controle para o método de chamada.

No seu caso você pode fazer uma chamada ao seu método Teste1 antes da instrução *return*

E você não pode fazer `return Teste1()` pois o *void* quando usado como o tipo de retorno para um método, ele especifica que o método não retorna um valor.

```
    public void Test1()
    {
    }

    public void Test2()
    {
        Test1();
        return;
       //nada mais será executado
    }

    public void Test3()
    {
        return;
    }
```

Basicamente poderíamos dizer que isso não pode acontecer por que é simplesmente como o [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/index) foi especificado pela equipe de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Acho que você subentendeu a motivação da pergunta.

Comment: Procurei contextualizar o do pq ele não pode fazer o return Teste1().